# What should I consider to analyze my proposed ILP in a scientific environment?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, integer-programming

I am working on an NP-complete problem and, I have proposed an efficient (as I think) Integer Linear programming to find the solutions in some small instances. My algorithm can work on a greater size instance in comparison to other studies. My tutor does not consider it sufficient to provide just one ILP algorithm and, asks me to analyze it as well. But, I don't know what should I do to show the efficiency of my algorithm, and what measure should be analyzed. In fact, I do not know what else to consider in addition to the ILP programming if I want to show my method in a scientific environment. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you ask your tutor?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, his field is not the computer and does not have enough information.

Comment: In that case, I would say that your tutor isn't in the position to state that providing an improved algorithm is not sufficient, and it needs to be analyzed as well.

Comment: We don't really know how to analyze heuristics such as integer programming. The best one can do in all by toy cases is to get empirical results.